# Trouble with creating a string array of int arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I need to create an array of integers contained within an array of words. I keep getting an error

> cannot convert from `int[]` to `java.lang.String[]`

where it says

```
private String[][] expenseName = {clothes, tuition, transportation, food, housing, books};
```

This is my code

```
public class Budget{

///////////////fields////////////////


int expenseAmount[] = {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000};
int monthNumber[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};


int clothes[]= {100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210};
int tuition[] = {200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200};
int transportation[]={100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210};
int food[]={80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80};
int housing[]={150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150};
int books[]= {200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int i=0; // this is arbitrary. Never hard code numbers unless that number is never going to change. in that case you make a variable and define it.
int month_num;
private String[][] expenseName = {clothes, tuition, transportation, food, housing, books};

/////////constructors///////////////
public Budget() {}

public Budget(int name) {this.expenseName[i][i] = name;}

public Budget(String name, int clothes, int tuition, int transportation, int food, int housing, int books)
{
this.expenseName[i] = name;
this.clothes[i] = clothes;
this.tuition[i] = tuition;
this.transportation[i] = transportation;
this.food[i] = food;
this.housing[i] = housing;
this.books[i] = books;
this.monthNumber[i] = month_num;
}


/////////////methods///////////
public String getexpenseName() {return expenseName[i][i];}

public int getclothes() {return clothes[i];}//change the I
public int gettuition() {return tuition[i];}
public int gettransporation() {return transportation[i];}
public int getfood() {return food[i];}
public int gethousing() {return housing[i];}
public int books() {return books[i];}
public int getmonthNumber() {return monthNumber[i];}//change the i

public void setExpenseName(String name)
{
this.expenseName[i][i] = name;
}

public boolean setexpenseAmount(int num)
{
if (this.expenseAmount[i] == 0)
{this.expenseAmount[i] = num;
return true;
}
else
return false;
```

Comment: Why do you declare the array as `String` if it is `int`? *(scratching head)*

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around your strings:

```
private String[] expenseName = {"clothes", "tuition", "etc"};
```

or you need to declare it int[][]

```
private int[][] expenseName = {clothes, tuition};
```

Comment: I don't think that your first snippet is what the OP wants. But even if it is, you have a slight mistake: You are declaring an array of array of strings, but only providing an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message **clearly** states, you can't put an `int[]` into an array of `String[]`s.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
private String[][] expenseName = {clothes, tuition, transportation, food, housing, books};
```

to

```
private int[][] expenseName = {clothes, tuition, transportation, food, housing, books};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you cannot use an array of int as an array of String.

That will just not work, like the error says.

I guess that you must be familiar with some language where there is no type checking and you can do whatever you want.  But this is Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `int[]` to `String[]`, for example like this.

```
public class ArrayIntToString {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
    String[] numbersAsStrings = new String[numbers.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        numbersAsStrings[i++] = number.toString();
    }
}
}
```